# Tableau to click on datapoint, populate another panel

Tags: storyboard, tableau-api, gis, datapoint

I'm using trial version of Tableau Desktop 9.0.4

So far, I have datapoints on a geographic map. When I hover over them, the information appears in the tool tip.

Here is abstract of map

[image]

Now, I am trying to find out how to display other data on a separate panel, i.e. I click on datapoint, and data appears on the panel below.

This is abstract of what I would like. What Tableau tools to use? Thanks!

[image]

@Inox For some reason, `Use as Filter` is greyed out. I even tried to remove QuickFilters. Screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Try filter actions. http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/Filter-Actions

Comment: @Inox The `Use as Filter` is greyed out, I updated my original question. Please advise.

Comment: Actions are available under the Dashboard menu on a dashboard. You'll need a target worksheet. Try the free video training at http://www.tableau.com.

Comment: @AlexBlakemore Oh ok, I selected a worksheet in Dashboard and clicked on Actions. Now I can see options. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said in the comments, you should use [Action Filters](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/combining-sheet-links-and-dashboards) to use data from one worksheet to the other, if both are displayed in the same dashboard. *(In fact, you can even filter worksheets in other dashboards, but I don't believe it's the case right now).*

In Tableau Desktop, select **Worksheet** → **Actions** and then click in the **Add Action** button.

Selecting the filter action, you will be prompted with a window that lets you select the source sheet, target sheet and how the filter should behave.

[image: Filter Action]